# hiding element but fadeToggle() not working

Tags: jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').hide();

    $('h3#work').click(function() {
        $('#slider').fadeToggle('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

This jQuery code is supposed to toggle a fading in/out box but the the first line with `hide()` is overriding it!

It works without the `hide()`, so I must need some sort of conditional.  Any tips?

Here is the HTML Code:

```
<div id="content_slider">

     <div id="slider">            
            <div id="slider_holder"><!-- slider content below-->
        <ul id="slider1"><!-- master holder slider -->

            <li><!-- derm surg-->
            <div id="wrapper_2">

              <div id="video">
              <iframe width="400" height="275" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/4Ty0dGHpzt8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
              </div>
              <div id="text">
              <h2><a href="http://www.dermsurgscientific.com">Dermsurg Scientific</a></h2>
              <p>
            Web Developer for Dermsurg Scientific, a medical start-up that has designed and built a new surgical model for doctors to train their facial surgery skills in all types of suturing and tumor removal.

              <br/>
              <br/>

                      I did the design, development and used Magento for our store
                      </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            </li>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `$('#slider').fadeOut(0);` instead of `$('#slider').hide();`

Comment: That almost works, but the #slider still does not fadeIn.  I'll keept trying.

Comment: There is probably something else going to here. Would be helpful to see the code.

Comment: Got it working, needed to simplifly some HTML code, thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/V83kg/

Comment: In my #slider div I have a slideshow and other stuff, but it doesn't pop up.

Comment: maybe the element, in which #slider is in, is hidden, too? Show us a little bit more code..

Comment: I checked my css and there is no display or visibility properties attached to the #slider div elements.  I didn't include the closing divs either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the fadeToggle callback

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('h3#work').click(function()
        {
            $('#slider').fadeToggle('slow', function()
            {
                $('#slider').hide();
            });
        });
    });

</script>
```